# Know windows username via WebScripting

Tags: windows, wsh

Hello to you all again dear coders,

I was wondering if it is possible to get the Windows/Mac/Linux username of the pc via Web scripting (Javascript, PHP, ASP.NET, Java , Flash.. Everything)

I know that usually web-scripting hasn't got access to the machine, but I'm here to know the opinion of you all.

Please try to help me, i really need to find out a solution.

Thanks in advance.
Fox.

Comment: You can get the username if Windows authentication is used. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013692/getting-windows-username-with-javascript