# Retrieve Username after IIS Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, iis, windows-authentication

I have a basic site (HTML/JavaScript) which is using IIS authentication (Windows Authentication) to restrict access.
[IIS authentication setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8klC.png)

After a user logs on to the site I need to then display their userID.

How can I retrieve the logged in userID knowing the site being restricted is simply HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Code running in the browser won't know that. You need server side JavaScript, or Node.js backend.

Comment: @LexLi - What would be the simplest way to implement server side JavaScrript to pass the user id to the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script language="javascript">
   var username = '<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';
</script>
```

There is a similar problem to yours in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013692/getting-windows-username-with-javascript), you can refer to the answer

Comment: My JavaScript is all on the client side.

Comment: It may be difficult to use client script to retrieve username.User authentication is done in iis, that is, on the server side. If the client script can obtain user information on the server, it would be a huge security risk.